# Kibana not mobile friendly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am looking for a frontend to query Elasticsearch, I know that Kibana is the best option for this (Besides grafana).

Unfortunately Kibana is totally not mobile friendly on android. Search is a real headache...

Tried searching on google but not able to find a worthy alternative.
Someone has experience on other tools/making kibana perform better on mobile devices.

If this turns out to be nothing I am seriously considering writing an angular app to perform base searches myself. Delivering in the dynamicniss of Kibana itself :(

Comment: This is work in progress, see [this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2563) and [this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/16717). Their new [UI framework](https://elastic.github.io/eui/#/) will support better responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks, previously we were using version 5.6 of Kibana. 6.3 is already a big improvement

Comment: And 7 will be even more ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is painful to use web version of kibana on ipad, although they claim it is mobile friendly.

I see a recent post on elastic forum, that a native iphone/ipad kibana go is now available, a very nice start.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ios-mobile-app/218463

You can download the app and check out the demo dashboard, to connect to your own ELK, you will need to install a kibana plugin then pointing to your own kibana.

Comment: Check out this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/octagon-analytics-native-ios-mobile-app-for-kibana/223868

Comment: Is Kibana for mobile (Kibana Go, available only in ios platform) restricted based on country / location ? Am not able to view or download in India but folks in U.S can.